# Different ways to sort data in SSIS

Tags: sorting, ssis

I know there can be 2 ways to sort data in SSIS data flow.

1. Use sort transformation.
2. Use Order by Clause in Input Query.

Are any other ways to sort my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a third party tool named **[NSort](http://www.ordinal.com/ssis.html)** which is very much used for sorting the data in SSIS.

> NSort brings world-record sorting technology to SSIS, cutting sorting
>   time by 70% or more while eliminating the need to restructure the
>   project into RAM-sized partitions. By carefully using temporary files
>   NSort easily processes data sets dozens or hundreds of times the size
>   of memory. Users typically find that data is processed as fast as it
>   is read, while using even less cpu time than the standard sort.

Answer (score 2):

And you can use a asynchronous script component to sort but be advised that sorting in SSIS is going to be an asynchronous process regardless which results in memory copies as well as acting as a blocking component.

My general rule is that if you can do it in the database, you're likely to be better off from a performance perspective.